# Create UIButton on top layer UITableViewController like as AirBnB

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button

How to create UIButton in **UITableViewController** like as `AirBnB map`.

Highlighted in red in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Add the element to top view (outside of UITableView) and add constraints to right and bottom.

Comment: Add the element to image view and add constraints to bottom , right , height and width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy actually, just create the table view as you always do (either storyboard or code) then create the button, position it correctly, set constraints and make sure **it's not a subview of the table view** but the view that contains the table view.

Since you didn't specify whether you use the storyboard or not, I did use it for the example below.

See this extremely simple demo I've just created:
[image]

This is the view hierarchy:

[image]

And these are the constraints for the button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a button first and then then override the function scrollViewDidScroll():

```
 import UIKit

 class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 private let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let image = UIImage(named: "Image.png")
    button.frame = CGRect(x: yourXpos, y: yourYPos, width: 60, height: 60)
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)),    for:.touchUpInside)
    areaOfTableView.addSubview(button)
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let  offset = self.areaOfTableView.contentOffset.y

   button.frame = CGRect(x: yourXpos, y:   offset + yourYpos, width: btn.frame.size.width, height: btn.frame.size.height)
  }

@objc private func buttonClicked(_ button: UIButton) {
    // Action when you tapped the button
   }

}
```